# How do I run an external file within Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

At the moment I'm using the ["gulp-run" plugin](https://github.com/cbarrick/gulp-run) to run a .bat file. That plugin has now been deprecated and I'm looking for the best way to execute the .bat now.

**Current code:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var run = require('gulp-run');

module.exports = function() {

    run('c:/xxx/xxx/runme.bat').exec();

};
```

**Solution** as per @cmrn suggestion:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var batchLocation = 'c:/xxx/xxx/runme.bat';
gulp.task('task', function (cb) {
  exec(batchLocation, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to run the script as part of a gulp stream (i.e. in `pipe()`) you can use [*gulp-exec*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec). If not, you can just use `child_process.exec` as described in the *gulp-exec* README, copied below.

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('task', function (cb) {
  exec('ping localhost', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response cmrn! So I got it working with child_process as you suggested (see code above under "Working code as per @cmrn suggestion")

I'm wondering what's the reason I would use "gulp-exec" over the child_process method? You mention, if I'm running the script "as part of my gulp pipeline". Aren't both ways mentioned part of the gulp pipeline?

*Sorry, I'm new to Gulp / Node / JS*

Comment: Sure. You would use *gulp-exec* where you need to run the script for each file that the task is processing. In that case, you'd use *gulp-exec* from within the `pipe()` command. For example, `gulp.src('./**/*.css').pipe(exec("example.bat <%= file.path %>"));` would call *example.bat* for each CSS file in your project, with the filename as the first argument.